# Can't get variable from included file PHP

Tags: php, file, include

I have this file (config.php)

```
<?php

session_start();

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "sklep-3jt");

?>
```

And this

```
<?php

include "config.php";
echo $db;

?>
```

The point is that error show that $db variable is undefined. Why?

Comment: Try setting another variable `$variable2 = "TEST"` .. See if that echos.

Comment: Maybe the  `config.php` isn't well included ? At the wrong place?

Comment: Since $db is a connection string, shouldn't you be doing a connection test instead of trying to echo it out?

Comment: I'm stupid, Vincent you were right, it was in wrong place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code from config.php assigns mysqli class instance into $db variables. So there is not string in this variable as someone alaready said. If you want to verify that db is connected, try something like in examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php

Also, I strongly recommend using PDO instead of mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

First: define another variable like a string to be able to echo the string.
Second: Check for path and capitalization (Config.php vs config.php)